# How to automatically detect new emails with python

Tags: python, email

I have code that reads from my gmail inbox using IMAP

```
import imaplib
import email

email_address = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Placeholder
email_pass = 'mypassword' # Placeholder

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(email_address, email_pass)
mail.select('inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

if len(id_list) > num_of_mail:
    print('New Mail Found...\n')

    for i in range(int(id_list[-1]), int(id_list[0]) -1, -1):
        typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_from = msg['from']
                email_body = msg.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
                print('\nFrom: %s' % email_from)
                print('\nSubject: %s' % email_subject)
                print('\nEmail Body: %s \n' % email_body)
```

This works fine but I have to run the program everytime I want to read my emails.
How can I put this code in a loop so that everytime I recieve a new email it automatically detects it and prints the content or maybe writes it to a text file ?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
import imaplib
import email

email_address = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Placeholder
email_pass = 'mypassword' # Placeholder

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(email_address, email_pass)

num_of_mail = 0

while True:

    mail.select('inbox')

    type, data = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
    mail_ids = data[0]
    id_list = mail_ids.split()

    if len(id_list) > num_of_mail:
        print('New Mail Found...\n')

        for i in range(int(id_list[-1]), int(id_list[0]) -1, -1):
            typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

            for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                    email_subject = msg['subject']
                    email_from = msg['from']
                    email_body = msg.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
                    file = open('EMAIL.txt','w')
                    file.write(email_from)
                    file.write(email_subject)
                    file.write(email_body)
                    file.close()
        num_of_mail = len(id_list)
```

When I run this, it finds any unseen emails that I already have but if I get new email after I've run the program, it doesnt detect it. Why is that ? It's looking through the ids everytime so it should detect new email if it sees it. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import imaplib, serial, struct, time
class Mail():
    def __init__(self):
        self.user= 'USER'
        self.password= 'PASS'
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem621', 9600)
        self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
        self.M.login(self.user, self.password)      
    def checkMail(self):
        self.M.select()
        self.unRead = self.M.search(None, 'UnSeen')
        return len(self.unRead[1][0].split())  
    def sendData(self):
        self.numMessages= self.checkMail()
        #turn the string into packed binary data to send int
        self.ser.write(struct.pack('B', self.numMessages))       
email = Mail()
# check for new mail every minute
while 1:
    print 'Sending'
    email.sendData()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I got an import error for serial. I tried installing it but pip didn't find it.